# python type: types of the attribute of a new class

Tags: python, class, types, attributes, typing

It is possible to create a new class using the `type` function.

For example:

```
C = type('C',(object,),{'a':1, 'b':"value"})
```

The above create a new class 'C', subclass of 'object' and with attributes 'a' and 'b'.

As one could expect, the attribute `a` is of type `int`.

```
c = C()
type(c.a)
```

> int

Would it be possible to set the types of the attributes to something more specific?
For example, I could prefer `a` to be of type `typing.Optional[int]`.

If something similar could be used by another method (i.e. not using the `type` function), I would also be happy to know.

Comment: You can't. `typing` only deals with type checking before run time. That's why they are called "type hints" . `Optional[int]` is not a valid run-time Python type.

Answer (score 0):

@DeepSpace is right with their comment, `Optional[int]` is not a valid-run-type type. By calling

```
C = type('C', (object,), {'a': 1, 'b': 'value'})
```

You're creating a class that is equivalent to:

```
class C:
    a = 1
    b = 'value'
```

If you want to create a class like:

```
class D:
    a: int | None = 1
    b: str = 'value'
```

Then, you have to specify your `__annotations__` directly:

```
import typing

D = type('D', (object,), { 'a': 1, 'b': 'value',
    '__annotations__': {
        'a': typing.Optional[int],
        'b': str
    }
})
```

Note that this still doesn't make `type(D.a)` report `Optional[int]` since, like @DeepSpace said, type annotations are just that - they are not runtime types!